# How can I cap the framerate at 60fps?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl

Alright, so I'm trying to cap my framerate at 60 frames per second, but the method I'm using is slowing it down to like 40.

```
#define TICK_INTERVAL 30

Uint32 TimeLeft(void){
    static Uint32 next_time = 0;
    Uint32 now;

    now = SDL_GetTicks();
    if ( next_time <= now ) {
        next_time = now+TICK_INTERVAL;
        return(0);
    }
    return(next_time-now);
}
```

Then I call it like this: `SDL_Delay(TimeLeft());`

How can I cap my framerate without going over it, or having it cap it too soon?

Comment: Why do you need to cap the framerate? This question has popped up a few times lately, and the solution is (almost always) *don't* cap, adjust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to record the time *before* drawing the current frame, and then delay the appropriate amount from *then*.

For example, some pseudo code to do it would be

```
markedTime = currentTime();
drawFrame(); 
delayFrom(markedTime, 1/60);
```

markedTime is the time recorded before drawFrame() was called. delayFrom() is a function that delays from a given time instead of "now". 1/60 is the amount of time to delay from the first argument, in seconds.

Comment: Not following you. can you post a example?

Comment: `markedtime = currentTime();` `drawFrame();` `delayFrom(markedTime, 1/60);`

Comment: Okay, I get that, except for delayFrom. MarkedTime and 1/60. whats the relationship between the two?

Comment: `markedTime` is the time recorded before `drawFrame()` was called. `delayFrom()` is a function that delays from a given time instead of "now". `1/60` is the amount of time to delay from the first argument, in seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't seem to figure this out today. Could you tell me how I would delay 1/60 from the first arg.?

Comment: It took you `x` seconds to draw the frame. In order to delay 1/60 of a second from the first time, you must further delay `1/60 - x` seconds.